# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core' in 'C:\Users\Meenakshi\OneDrive\Documents\react apps\memories\client\src'

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a web application which uses MERN. I have installed @material-ui/core but it is throwing an error like **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core'** in 'C:\Users\Meenakshi\OneDrive\Documents\react apps\memories\client\src' My import files are-

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import memories from "./images/memories.png";
```

And the dependencies looks like-

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
}
```

I'm importing it using the command-

```
    $ npm install @material-ui/core
```

and have also tried-

```
    $ npm install i @material-ui/core
```

Comment: what version of mui are you using? v4? or latest v5.x? you can find this in package.json

Comment: In your dependencies , there is no @material-ui/core is installed.. please check the directory in your terminal you are installing ..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing whole material ui core, you can import specifically what you need.

**for version 4.x**
Examples:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import { Box, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
```

and in your package.json

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
```

**if using version 5.x**

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
```